# Writing text char by char alignment problem

Tags: php

I am trying to write text using imagettftext PHP function, character by character

I have to write it character by character because colors for different characters are different

This is my code

```
$text= 'VagMineTech';
$text= str_split( $text );
$x=100; $y=100;
foreach( $text as $v ) {
    imagettftext( $img, 30, 0, $x, $y, $color[$v], $font, $v );
    $box= imagettfbbox( 30, 0, $font, $v );
    $x= $x + $box[2];
}
```

This code is working ok, but in some cases, current character is getting written too far away from the previous character.

Please take a look at this image to understand what is happening.

[image]

The colored image on top is the problem image.
Notice the difference in distance between "V" and "a", then again in "T" and "e"

The second image on that same link is the correct image, but it's a single color image.

I want my colored image to look like the second image, but in colors...

How can I do this?

Please note that I cannot move these 2 characters to the left just this one time.
There are different fonts, different text to write.

Comment: VagMine hue hue hue

Comment: can you provide the original PHP script. Where do you change the color? Which font you are using (maybe depends on font)?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, yes, its a font issue, I understand that. Its not coming up in "non-italic" fonts. Only in italic fonts. The color is changing in this line, $color is an array, which stores needed color for respective text.   imagettftext( $img, 30, 0, $x, $y, $color[$v], $font, $v );

Comment: If you're writing things letter by letter, what you're doing is completely ignore the fact that correct text placement is _the font's_ responsibility, which it can _only_ do if you pass it full strings, not individual characters.

Comment: Ok, so cannot handle this at font end, but can I handle it at my end somehow? Or is there any other way to color the second text without writing char by char? Either is good enough for me. My purpose is to color the text with different colors instead of writing the whole thing with just one color.

Comment: Darn keming problems